# Nginx configuration for gitlab

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gitlab-omnibus

I struggle with a problem to conf my nginx reverse proxy to work with gitlab.
Let's say that my gitlab server's IP is 192.168.0.2:8888 on my network. This server is not accessible throught internet. And my proxy is accessible by http://example.org
Due to somes reasons, I can't use subdomain, so I want to configure my proxy to access gitlab throught http://example.org/git.
My nginx proxy is working fine for my other needs and my gitlab server work great on local.

I try this config on my proxy :

```
...
location /git {
  proxy_path http://192.168.0.2:8888;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

But when I go to http://example.org/git, I get redirect to http://example.org/users/sign-in. I lost the "git" folder in the url.
I try many thing in this config, adding a "/" at the end of the proxy_path, adding "rewrite ^/git(.*) /$1 break;", etc.
At best, I get the right redirect, http://example.org/git/users/sign-in, but all the resources lead to http://example.org/{resource}

I'm noob at nginx config so I don't know what to try now.
If someone can lead me to the right direction :)

Thx

Comment: You need to configure gitlab so that it runs as `http://192.168.0.2:8888/git/` Then the proxy_pass would work. You need to configure your gitlab and set a non-root path/base url

Comment: @TarunLalwani yeah this is what I figured yesterday. I will try to follow this guide https://gitlab.com/help/install/relative_url.md, after work.
But I think this is the solution, thx